# Overlapping legend in r plot

Tags: r, plot, graphics

I've tried with this code, but the legend overlaps the plot. I would like to put the legend at the bottom of the picture (centered under the plot), and I also would like to adjust the size of the example lines in the legend, because the also overlap texts.

```
plot(Portfolio.z, plot.type ="single", main ="Portfolio",
          col =c("red", "blue", "green", "black", "yellow", "purple"),
          lty =c("solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid", "solid"),
          lwd =2, ylab = "Price")
par(xpd=TRUE)
legend("bottom",legend = c("JP Morgan", "Goldman Sachs",
          "BP", "ExxonMobil", "Lockheed Martin", "Boeing"),
          text.width = min(sapply(c("JP Morgan", "Goldman Sachs",
          "BP", "ExxonMobil", "Lockheed Martin", "Boeing"), strwidth)),
          col=c("red", "blue", "black", "green", "purple",
          "yellow"), lwd=5, horiz = TRUE)
```

[image]

Comment: Do you have to use the base `R` plots? The `ggplot2` library has a much better API for creating and adjusting plots.

Comment: Yes, unfortunately I must stick to base plots.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be reading the manual page for legend - `?legend`: You have full control over every aspect of of the placement and font size. First, you do not have room for the legend below the x-axis unless you remove the x-axis label or increase the margin at the bottom (`?par`, argument `mar=`). The `inset=` argument in legend adjusts the position so something like `inset=c(0, -.15)` will put it below the axis, but you will may need to adjust the -.15 up or down. You also need to include `xpd=TRUE` so that R knows it is all right to put the legend in the margin below the plot. Finally, `cex=` controls the expansion of the text with 1 being the default:

```
plot(NA, xlim=c(0, 1), ylim=c(0, 1), xlab="")
legend("bottom", "A very long legend under the plot",
    xpd=TRUE, inset=c(0, -.15), cex=.8)
```

[image]